# Modifying multiple strings in a list

Tags: python, list

Here are my codes

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx.html"
webpage = requests.get(url)
page = bs(webpage.content, "html.parser")
images_List = []

for img in page.find("div", attrs={"class":"post-body entry-content"}).findAll("img"):
    images_List.append(img.get('src'))
```

From the above codes,I can get a list of images links

However,those images links have different patterns related to the images size

```
['https://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1800/xx.jpg',
'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1600/xx.jpg',
'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1200/xx.jpg',
'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/w1800/xx.jpg',
'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/w1600/xx.jpg',
'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/w1200/xx.jpg']
```

And I have used the codes below to change to size of the images to 5000

```
images_List = [n.replace('1800', '5000') for n in images_List]
images_List = [n.replace('1600', '5000') for n in images_List]
images_List = [n.replace('1200', '5000') for n in images_List]
```

However,sometimes it has more patterns of numbers other than s1800,s1600,s1200,w1800,w1600,w1200

I would like to ask if there is a more effective way to modify those links?
Other than copy and paste codes like

```
images_List = [n.replace('1800', '5000') for n in images_List]
images_List = [n.replace('1600', '5000') for n in images_List]
images_List = [n.replace('1200', '5000') for n in images_List]
images_List = [n.replace('1000', '5000') for n in images_List]
images_List = [n.replace('800', '5000') for n in images_List]
images_List = [n.replace('400', '5000') for n in images_List]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using a bunch of replace statements, you could use a regular expression with `re.sub`, which would look something like this:

```
import re

images = [
    'https://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1800/xx.jpg',
    'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1600/xx.jpg',
    'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1200/xx.jpg',
]
images = [re.sub("(?<=[sw])[0-9]{3,4}/", "5000/", image) for image in images]
```

This matches any substring that is preceded by "s" or "w" has 3 or 4 numbers and then a "/", and the substitutes if for "5000/".

Comment: What if the links are 
s1800,s1600,w1800,w1600,which I have to keep the s or w the same,just to modify the number part?
Thanks

Comment: I didn't realise you also had "w" cases. I'll make an edit to work for this case.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression uses positive lookahead and positive lookbehind to match the number.

```
import re

images_List = [
    "https://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1800/xx.jpg",
    "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1600/xx.jpg",
    "https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1200/xx.jpg",
]
images_List = [re.sub(r"(?<=\/[a-z])\d+(?=\/)", "5000", n) for n in images_List]
```

Comment: What if the links are s1800,s1600,w1800,w1600,which I have to keep the s or w the same,just to modify the number part? Thanks

Comment: @MaxChung I've updated the answer. now it should work for all of the described patterns.

Comment: You should upvote and accept the answer if "it works"

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `re.sub()`:

```
import re

images_List = ['https://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1800/xx.jpg',
               'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1600/xx.jpg',
               'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s1200/xx.jpg']

images_List = [re.sub('\d+', '5000', n) for n in images_List]

print(images_List)
```

Output:

```
['https://www.xxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s5000/xx.jpg',
 'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s5000/xx.jpg',
 'https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/xxxxx/s5000/xx.jpg']
```

---

---

`re.sub()` will look at the first argument passed into the brackets, which is the pattern we want to substitute,

then look at the second argument, which is the string we will use to substitute others,

and the last argument is the string we want to modify.

The pattern I have is: `'\d+'`, which tells re to look for series of numbers.